# SortedList/SortedDictionary weird behavior

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sorting

Can anybody explain why this code:

```
Dim Data As New SortedList(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
Data.Add("AB", 48)
Data.Add("AC", 48)
Data.Add("A-D", 48)
Data.Add("A-", 48)
```

Generates sorted list with following order:

```
A-  
AB  
AC  
A-D
```

Expected (logical and really wanted) order is:

```
A-
A-D
AB
AC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim Data As New SortedList(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

I think the problem is with the sort rules specified.

Changing `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` to `Ordinal` or `OrdinalIgnoreCase` solves the problem

```
Dim Data As New SortedList(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Here is the [Demo](http://ideone.com/Y8hLt1)

Comment: Correct. The invariant culture, like otter cultures in .NET, first strips away all dashes `-` and sees which string is greater then. If a greater string is found like that, that result is returned. Otherwise, the dashes are taken into consideration.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Why such special care for hyphen character ?

Answer (score 3):

That is how default string comparer is implemented. To customize this you have to implement your own custom `IComparer` or for better compatibility override `Comparer<T>` class and pass it to `SortedList` constructor or pass `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Comment: +1 The specific implementation of InvariantCultureIgnoreCase attempts to sort in a way which *has the same meaning* in all cultures. I'd venture a guess that the hyphen for non-ordinal alphabetizing is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking the comparer to act in a culturally indifferent way. This uses what the localization team feels is the most appropriate method such that consumers in different cultures will understand the sorting.

This is non-ordinal, so that not all characters are *automatically* considered and ranked.

I would venture a guess that the hyphens are ignored (conceptually concatenating words) for the purpose of alphabetic sorting.

You might suggest that "Ricky-Bobby" comes before "RickyBobby" but the localization team apparently disagreed. Consumers in all cultures will likely understand the sorting indifference between those two entries... and, furthermore, understand why **both** come before "Ricky-Charlie"