# String sorting gotcha

Tags: c#, sorting

I have following C# code compiled as Sort.exe:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = null;
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        while((text = Console.In.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            lines.Add(text);
        }

        lines.Sort();

        foreach(var line in lines)
            Console.WriteLine(line);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

I have a file input.txt which has following 5 lines as its content:

```
x000000000000000000093.000000000
x000000000000000000037.000000000
x000000000000000100000.000000000
x000000000000000000538.000000000
x-00000000000000000020.000000000
```

Now if I run it on command prompt following is the output:

```
C:\Users\girijesh\AppData\Local\Temp>sort < input.txt
x000000000000000000037.000000000
x000000000000000000093.000000000
x-00000000000000000020.000000000
x000000000000000000538.000000000
x000000000000000100000.000000000
```

I am not able to understand what kind of string sorting it is where string starting with `x-`(3rd line in output) comes in middle of strings starting with `x0`. Either 3rd line should have been at the top or at the bottom. Excel is also showing the same behaviour.

Comment: So, are you asking about the internal works of sorting strings? Or how to sort it so that the list is shown like the first one?

Comment: What happens when you use `lines = lines.OrderBy(line => line).ToList();` ?

Comment: @Nahuell he is asking why the Standard sort function seems to give incorrect results.

Comment: Your question would be better (IMO) if you got rid of the file handling part and just populated the `List<string>` inline. I have such code myself now, as it was easier to test - would you be happy for me to update the question?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087995/string-comparison-and-sorting-when-strings-contain-hyphens). Basically, hyphens are treated as "ignorable".

Comment: You will need `StringComparison.Ordinal` to fix it.

Comment: Sounds like Damien has the answer.  Gah!  All these clever locale-aware functions are sometimes more of a menace than a help.

Comment: Interestingly, in LINQPad on my machine, the `x-` line is *last*.

Comment: Related :[SortedList/SortedDictionary weird behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370734/sortedlist-sorteddictionary-weird-behavior) Possibly a duplicate.

Comment: @JonSkeet sir that was only to have a reproducible way to the problem. This problem even exists in SQL server order by clause. If a column contains those 5 values and we do an order by on the same column then result is same as above and there I don't know have the option StringComparer.Ordinal.

Comment: @user2176811: You don't need a file (or console input) to reproduce the problem though. Just populating the `List<string>` with: `var list = new List<string> { "...", "...", "...", "...", "..." };` with the same values reproduced the problem much more simply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In many cultures (including the invariant culture) the hyphen is a character that is of only minor importance for sorting purposes. In most texts, this makes sense: `pre-whatever` and `prewhatever` are pretty similar. For example, the following list is sorted as this, which I think is good:

```
preasdf
prewhatever
pre-whatever
prezxcv
```

You seem to want an [`Ordinal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) comparison, where values are compared purely by their unicode code point values.  If you change the line to:

```
lines.Sort(StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

Then your results are:

```
x-00000000000000000020.000000000
x000000000000000000037.000000000
x000000000000000000093.000000000
x000000000000000000538.000000000
x000000000000000100000.000000000
```

If you're wondering why the `-...20.0` value ended up where it did, consider what it'd look like if you removed the `-` (and compare with the above `pre` list).

```
x000000000000000000037.000000000
x000000000000000000093.000000000
x00000000000000000020.000000000
x000000000000000000538.000000000
x000000000000000100000.000000000
```

If your input is always in the format `x[some number]`, I'd parse the value after `x` as a `decimal` or `double`, and do the sorting on that. That would make it easier to ensure expected behavior, and overall better.

Comment: So the `-` character is not considered right? I mean without `ordinal` string `x-00000000000000000020` is same as `x00000000000000000020`?

Comment: @Rahul That's what I thought at first, but it's not quite right (that was for the soft hyphen, not the regular hyphen). I've amended my answer to clarify how hyphens are treated. They are of lower importance, but not none.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your answer and it explain pretty well but I am still in confusion as how sort is handling `-` in this case? Will have to find out.

Comment: I think it's equivalent to this (in the relatively simple examples here): first, compare the strings without the hyphens included. If the strings are different, use that comparison as the answer; if they're the same, then the one with the hyphen goes after the one without. This is why `prewhatever` and `pre-whatever` end up next to each other, and in between the other two.

Comment: Make total sense; I think sort is considering [a-z][A-Z][0-9] first and then going for special characters like -/;/etc.

Comment: Is there anything like StringComparer.Ordinal for SQL Server Order By or Excel sorting as well since these problem is present there too?

Comment: @user2176811, post that question as separate post for it to be isolated since these are two different technologies.