# Different sorting results on different CLR versions

Tags: c#, .net

While comparing strings in C#, different clr gives different results on Windows 7 sp1 x64. Here is sample code:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.AddRange(new[] { "!-", "-!", "&-l", "&l-", "-(", "(-", "-*", "*-", ".-", "-.", "/'", "-/" });
myList.Sort();
Console.WriteLine(Environment.Version);
myList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare("!-", "-!"));
Console.WriteLine("!-".CompareTo("-!"));
```

Here is the sample output:

---

If I set Target Framework to 4.0:

```
4.0.30319.18444
!-
-!
&l-
&-l
(-
-(
*-
-*
.-
-.
/'
-/

-1
-1
```

---

If I set Target Framework to 2.0:

```
2.0.50727.5485
-!
!-
&-l
&l-
-(
(-
-*
*-
-.
.-
-/
/'

1
1
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: In .NET 4.0 the Unicode changed from 5.0 to 5.1, so perhaps that is the difference. Sadly there is very little documentation on this

Comment: `List.Sort()` uses the default comparer, and the default comparer for `string` uses the current culture. This, in turn, depends on the collation tables supplied with .NET, and those are subject to change. If you want consistent results, use an ordinal-based comparison (`List.Sort(StringComparer.Ordinal)`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert The problem is present even with the InvariantCulture, that should be "stable"

Comment: No. The invariant culture is still a culture, and still depends on collation tables. The only thing guaranteed to be stable (as it does not depend on any collation at all) is ordinal-based comparison.

Comment: This has been already [discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087995/string-comparison-and-sorting-when-strings-contain-hyphens) and solution is to use [Ordinal comparer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19371082/2530848)

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Or `myList.Sort(string.CompareOrdinal);`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Using the Ordinal comparer is good only in limited cases, because with the Ordinal comparer `è > f`

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure that you are sorting with the [`MyList.Sort(StringComparer.Ordinal)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Unless Unicode start changing the code of their characters, it should provide a constant sorting order. Ordinal will be based off the actual code ID that were assigned to them.

If I take your first example comparing this :

```
-!
!-
```

The hyphen is **U+002D** and the exclamation mark is **U+0021**. Those codes haven't changed since at least the ASCII tables. I would consider checking your sorting parameters to make sure you compare only on ordinal and not on actual neutral/specific cultures.